# System.OutOfMemoryException with JSON.NET

Tags: json.net

Tried this with JSON.NET 6.0

```
DataSet ds = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>
("{\"tab1\":[{\"col1\":\"val1\"}]}"); // OK

DataTable dt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>
("{\"col1\":\"val1\"}"); // System.OutOfMemoryException
```

why?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's a bug, But if you want to deserialize DataSet or DataTable [this might help you](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer).

Answer (score 1):

The JSON in your second example represents a only a single row of data, not a `DataTable`.  A `DataTable` is an ordered collection of `DataRows`, therefore it needs to have square brackets in the JSON.  Try it like this instead:

```
string json = "[{\"col1\":\"val1\"}]";
DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```

I am not sure why you are getting an `OutOfMemoryException`; I get a `JsonSerializationException` when I try it, as I would expect.  Perhaps this was a bug that was fixed in [the most recent version of Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/121470).

Answer (score 0):

I have over come with this issue by creating JsonSerializer object. My code is as given below.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(yourfilePath))
{
    using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(r))
    {
         JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
         T lstObjects =  serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
    }
}
```

Here **yourfilePath** :- is your file current full path
 **T** :- is your object name, whether it could be Dataset, DataTable or any custom Object.